# how to run Python/ IPYNB (which uses pyspark/sklearn module)present locally on cloudera cluster

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cloudera

```
I have machine learning code written in 2 different files .py(python) and .ipynb(notebook). 
These scripts are present locally.Data is getting queried using sqlContext 
as data is stored on cloud (cloudera cluster)
```

Question is how to run .py/.ipynb (which are locally present) on cluster, so that they can access the data stored on cluster and generate the desired results.

Comment: You can store your results in tables using temp tables for temporary table or save table in the cloud.

Comment: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-13-x/topics/spark_ipython.html